# how to use a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, 2d

I am new in `C` and I am trying to create a 2D array of chars.
The logic behind this is to get unknown amount of string inputs
from the user and to be able to get to those strings 
(each string ends with a `":"`) but when I tried to debug I got:

```
<Error reading characters of string>
```

This is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int j = 0, rows = 50;
    int i=0, lines = 50;
    char **names;

    names = (char**)malloc(lines*sizeof(char*));

    if (i >= lines)
    {
        names = (char**)realloc(names, 10 * sizeof(char*));
        lines = lines * 10;
    }

    for (j ; names[i][j] != ':'; j++)
    {
        *names = (char*)malloc(rows * sizeof(char));

        if (j >= rows)
        {
            *names = (char*)realloc(names, 10 * sizeof(char));
            rows = rows * 10;
        }
        scanf("%c", &names[i][j]);
    }
    i++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: casting the return of malloc() and family is required only in C++, however not recommended in C.

Comment: if (i >=lines) will never execute

Answer (score 1):

```
for (j ; names[i][j] != ':'; j++)
```

In this loop your test condition tests for `':'` in `names` . `names` has been allocated memory but it does not contain any content (*what will it compare to ?*).

Use a `do-while` loop , in order to execute loop before reading characters in `names`.

Also you allocate memory for `char *`'s but you don't allocate memory to these pointers correctly . And without allocating memory correctly you try to store characters at location they point to . This will cause problem .

Allocate memory to each `char *` and then take input .

Some this like this can be done -

```
do{
     names[i] =malloc(rows * sizeof(char));
     if(names!=NULL){
      if (j >= rows) 
        {
           *names = (char*)realloc(names, 10 * sizeof(char));
           rows = rows * 10;
        }
       scanf("%c", &names[i][j]);
       j++;
       i++;
    }
}while(names[i][j]!=':')'
```

**Note**-

**1.** You should `free` the allocated memory . And you first `if` will not execute (*can't understand its use* ).

**2.** Check return of `malloc`.